# Georgia: How to get from Shatili to Tblisi in September

Tags: georgia-country

My brother and I are planning to make a trekking from Omalo to Shatili in the first week of September. One thing I'm a bit uncertain about is how easy it is to get back from Shatili to Tblisi. Acording to several sites, there are Marshrutka's running every Thursday and Sunday, but we will need to get back on Friday or Saturday.

I read somewhere that it is possible to hire a taxi driver for around 300 GEL. The price is not a problem, but how easy is it to arrange a taxi there (It seems that the village is very small). Is there anything that can be arranged up front?